# Linq MVC5 MSQL select some columns from a table containing larg amount of columns in order to make better and fast query

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, query-optimization

For example a table that is containing like 30 columns

```
table1{col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6....,col30}
```

here we can do like

```
        List<table1> result = (from a in dbconn.table1.AsEnumerable()

                                        select new table1
                                        {
                                            col1= a.col1,
                                            col2= a.col2
                                        }).ToList();
        return result.ToList();
```

same as

```
 SELECT 
[Extent1].[col1] AS [col1], 
[Extent1].[col2] AS [col2],
[Extent1].[col3] AS [col3], 
....
....
....
[Extent1].[col30] AS [col30], 
FROM [dbo].[table1] AS [Extent1]
```

-> almost 2 minutes

but this is not correct because while doing this i am checking the result in **SQL Server Profiler**  the result of this linq query is getting all the table ***table1*** data then dumping to new table1 which is time consuming.

now this makes the query very slow because larg amount of data is there so in sql we can just

```
select col1,col2 from table1
```

-> almost 2 seconds

how can we do it in linq with out getting the full table and make the linq same or near to SQL.

Comment: Why `AsEnumerable()` ?

Comment: @Serg because i need the result in Enum you can use Array too, but my case is list

Comment: You needn't do it within LINQ query, I guess

Comment: @Serg, i thing that will not make performance effect but i did it because my view was in list so i could not use array.

Answer (score 0):

AsEnumerable() is effectively a cast to IEnumerable, which makes member resolution find members of Enumerable instead of Queryable. It's usually used when you want to force part of a query to run as SQL (or similar), and the remainder to run using LINQ to Objects.

```
(from a in dbconn.table1
     select new
     {
         col1= a.col1,
         col2= a.col2
     }).ToList();
```

Also, check indexes - will speed up more

Answer (score 0):

The first rule to remember when working with LINQ to SQL is next:

Calling `.ToList()`, .`ToArray()`, `.ToDictionary()` and `.AsIEnumerable()` performs query materialization which means that your `IQueryable` will be transformed to SQL with all `.Where()`, `.Select()`, `.Order()` (etc.) predicates BEFORE it and will be executed.

In your example, you called `.AsEnumerable()` directly on DbSet which means you will execute query without any predicates or limits and all data from this database table will be pushed to the memory and only after that your `.Where()` and `.Select()` will be applied, right in the memory